# Printing and saving files in java applets

Tags: java, client-side, applet

we have this problem: we want to save files or print from java applet in browser, but this could not be easily implemented, as java applets don't seem to have rights for calling OS services. Is there any way to implement these two functionalities (maybe with server help etc.). What would you suggest?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing resources outside the Applet sandbox, you'll need to sign your Applet, and set up the access privilieges at a policy file.

[Here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/applets/) you can find a quite complete guide on Applets Security.

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution was very simple :). In Netbeans -> Project properties -> Application/Web Start/{check the self-signed checkbox}. That's it with all certifications

Answer (score 0):

Tomas is right. But probably I can suggest you a workaround. You can implement your print through browser. This does not require additional security permissions and applet might be unsigned.

To call javascript API from applet the applet must have attribute MAYSCRIPT and use netscape.javascript.JSObject. Yes, netscape! The name remained as a monument for this died browser.